# Quadratic congruences equivalent statements

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-residues

Prove that for every prime $p>3$,

$L= x^2-x+2 \equiv 0\mod p$ has a solution iff $D=x^2-x+16 \equiv 0\mod p$ has a solution.

This is not true, right?
If $L \equiv 0$ mod$p$, then $D=L+14 \equiv 14\mod p$, and $14$ is not congruent to $0\mod p$, when $p \neq 7$.

Comment: I think it's true.

Comment: What's wrong with my reasoning then ?

Comment: You are assuming that the $x$ that solves the first congruence is the same as the $x$ that solves the second.

Comment: Duplicate of [Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that there exists $x∈Z$ for which $p|x^2−x+ 3$ if and only if there exists $y∈Z$ for which $p|y^2−y+ 25$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680151/let-p-be-a-prime-number-prove-that-there-exists-x%e2%88%88z-for-which-px2%e2%88%92x-3)

Comment: @BillDubuque Can you give me a link on something that explains connection between discriminant and quadratic congruences ?

Comment: @someone **Completing the square** is *universal*, i.e. it works over any commutative ring, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229251/242). Seel also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29878/quadratic-polynomial-over-k/29893#29893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first congruence has solutions if and only if $\Delta_1=-7$ is a square$\bmod p$.

The second congruence has solutions if and only if  $\Delta_2=-63$ is a square$\bmod p$.

Now it is obvious that 
$$-7 \,\text{ is a square}\bmod p\iff-63=3^2\cdot -7 \,\text{ is a square}\bmod p.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(2x-1)^2\equiv-7\pmod p$$

$$(2y-1)^2\equiv-63\equiv\{3(2x-1)\}^2$$

Comment: $[3(2x-1)]^2$ right ?

Comment: @someone, Yes, true.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

The discriminant of $x^2-x+2$ is $-7$.

The discriminant of $x^2-x+16$ is $-63=3^2(-7)$.